# How to fix the (Safari and IE) overflow issue in Angular?

Tags: angular, overflow

To get a div scrollable I use the CSS overflow:auto. This doesn't work in IE and Safari but only in Chrome. In the failing browsers I am forced to put a fixed height in the CSS of the same DIV.

As many others I want my application to be able to resize. So, using the offsetTop property and some typescript calculation on a resize event seems to work. I am manipulating the DIV directly in DOM which is, as I discovered here, not the best way.

I have 2 problems;

1. I want to do the calculation on application startup and not only after a resize event. Using the Angular lifecycle hooks I keep getting wrong calculations. I think the DOM is not settled down yet.
2. I would like to bind to the {style: height=XXpx} property of the DIV with an angular directive but I get this error:
   *"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'height: 728px'. Current value: 'height: 715px'"*

Consider me a dinosaur as classical developer but a baby doing Angular and javascript at this moment in my life. I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT AFTER SOME HELP:

The answer of Koudela helped me a great deal in finding out that the second pass of ngAfterViewChecked provided me with the correct property values of the element. Now I could perform the correct calculation and put the correct height in the list. The ngAfterViewChecked worked for both initial en resize.

I found a new challenge though; I need to repeat this trick for all components in my app that have a scrollable div. The calculation will be different for all individual div's. I doesn't feel right to create a separate directive for each scrollable div. Furthermore I would like to have the resize calculation code in the component itself. Is there a way to get a reference to a component class function from within the external directive?

Comment: 'I want my application to be able to resize'  did you try media queries?

Comment: @Vega Thanks Vega but media queries are not linear enough. Using flexboxes everything works like a charm except for the scrollable areas.

Comment: With recalculating you can resize divs, but how do you manage elements positions, layouts? For exemple I move around the divs if it's for a phone landscape or portrait presentation? Isn't it too much work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple resize directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[doResize]'
})
export class DoResizeDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('doResize') size: number;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.doResize(null);
    }

    private doResize(size: number) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.height = (size || this.size || 20) + 'px';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div [doResize]="200"></div>
```

Example Plunk: http://embed.plnkr.co/thIHksY1ZzIHVCpiLmfj/

Adding your calculation should be straight forward.

If you keep getting the wrong calculation, check the individual values in the lifecycle hooks using something like `console.log(yourElement.clientHeight)`.

Consider ngDoCheck(), ngOnChanges() or @HostListener for changes after initial page load or interactivity.

Official guide: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Thanks Koudela! You gave me a detailed push in the right direction. Using your directive I found out that the second pass of ngAfterViewChecked provided the correct offsetHeight I could use for my calculation. It presented me with a new challenge I will describe with an edit of my original question.